# Can't get Content Approval Workflow to work

Tags: workflow, publishing, approval-process, content, content-approval

I recently created a new Document Library for our manager to manage and approve what goes on there by our content owner. I followed [this document by Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742) but unfortunately I don't receive any email notification nor there are any items in the Workflow Tasks list to approve.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Library **Settings** > **Versioning**
2. Ticked **Yes** on "Content Approval".
3. Ticked **Create major and minor versions** on "Document Version History"
4. Ticked **Yes** on "Require Check out"
5. Library **Settings** > **Advanced Settings**
6. Ticked **Yes** on "Content Types". Now I have a "Document" content type.
7. Ticked **New experience** on "List experience"
8. Library **Settings** > **Workflows**
9. Clicked on "Add a workflow"
10. Selected **Document** from "Content Type" (instead of the default "This List")
11. Selected ***Approval - Sharepoint 2010** from "Workflow"
12. Entered name "Submission Approval"
13. Selected **Tasks** from "Task List"
14. Selected **Workflow History** from "History List"
15. Only "Allow this workflow to be manually started..." is ticked under "Start Options"
16. Clicked **Next**
17. Entered my company email (it's office 365 so it checked out)
18. Selected **One at a time** for "Order"
19. Ticked for "Expand Groups"
20. I didn't enter a due date, however I selected a "Duration Per Task" and entered 5.
21. Ticked "Enable Content Approval"
22. Clicked **Save**

After that I submit a word document on that Library for publishing by selecting "Publish", hit ok and wait but nothing shows up in the Tasks list or email notification either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nvm, turns out I need to check "Creating a new item will start this workflow" for **Start Options** during "Add a workflow" creation process (obviously you can go back and edit it too).

Gosh!